# Trying to add normal distribution curve to ggplot, and it's not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried looking at some of the other answers on this, but got confused.

I have a histogram of some sample data, which plots ok.  I'm trying to overlay a normal distribution curve over it for comparison sake.  I'm using ggplot.  I'm trying to use stat_function for the curve, and it just won't display.

This part might sound confusing, but are both of the args in stat_function supposed to be independent from the underlying histogram, or does one of them have to be the same.  I'm just looking at some other sample code, and in that case it looks like they used mean from histogram and sd was stated (or vice versa).[image]

Here's my code:

```
sim_cnt<-1000
lambda<-.2
samp_sz<-40
set.seed(222)
mn<-1/lambda
st_dv<-1/lambda
mns<-sapply(1:sim_cnt,function(x){mean(rexp(samp_sz,lambda))})

library(ggplot2)

g<-ggplot(data=data.frame(mns), aes(x=mns))+ geom_histogram(binwidth=.3, fill="red", color="green")+geom_vline(xintercept=mean(mns),size =1, col="black")+labs(x="Means")+ggtitle("Sample Distribution")+stat_function(fun=dnorm, color="pink",args=list(sd=.7905694,mean=5))
g
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The other one was using underlying data.  This one is using comparison data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the colors red and green for you because red-green color blindness is the most common hereditary color deficiency. I multiply the count by .3 so that the bandwidth of the density plot matches that of the histogram binwidth.

```
g<-ggplot(data=data.frame(mns), aes(x=mns))+ 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=.3, fill="red", color="blue")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=mean(mns),size =1, col="black")+
  labs(x="Means")+ ggtitle("Sample Distribution")
g + stat_density(aes(y = .3 * ..count..), geom = "line",
                 color = "blue", size = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  That's a start.  I'm concerned about the "lumpiness" of the curve, I guess which comes from multiplying by count.  Not sure.  Any way to have the curve smooth?  The curve is not supposed to be using the data of the histogram, but just displaying a normal distribution curve so that I can compare it to the histogram.

Comment: Ah, distribution not density. The lumpiness of this density plot is due to the sampling variation from your procedure. The reason that I made this mistake is that you are plotting a histogram of counts instead of frequencies. Since you are doing so, it makes comparison to the normal density which will have a y value less than .5. You will note this in the other duplicate question's solution.

Comment: I looked at the duplicate one, but it seems to be wanting to put a curve of the underlying data over the histogram of the underlying data, which is not what I'm doing.  Also, I see from a mistake in my assignment that the theoretical standard deviation was listed wrong.  It should be 0.7905694, not 5.  The sd of the underlying data is 0.808.

Comment: I had to add "aes(y=..density..)" to my histogram.

Comment: The answer on the other page is plotting what you are looking for. Just to make sure you have the right thing, it is dmns =  data.frame(mns)
`ggplot(data= dmns, aes(x=mns)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), fill="red", color="blue",
                 position="identity", binwidth=.5) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept=mean(mns),size =1, col="black")+ 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, color="blue", args=list(mean=mn, sd=.79))`